# Close Ajax popup panel but with postback and ignore regular expression validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, regex

How can i hide an ajax popup that would cause a postback but would ignore validations.

In my case, i have a validator for a textbox with minimum value of 0.

[image]

but whenever i click cancel, it cant proceed due to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set "CausesValidation" property on the cancel button to "False". 
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx